Stacked much greater than much less than symbol in latex
I'm trying to use a symbol as shown in the picture where there is "much greater than" symbol with "much less than" symbol right under it. I did some search and found \gtrless in amssymb. However, \gtrless does "greater than" instead of "much greater than" and "less than" instead of "much less than". I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.


Possible duplicate: What is a simple way to create a binary relation symbol on top of another?

Something like this?

Note that I'm assuming that this composite symbol is supposed to be a binary operator. If it's supposed to be a relational operator, just replace \mathbin with \mathrel in the code shown below.
And, do note that this symbol shouldn't be used in \scriptstyle and \scriptscriptstyle settings, i.e., in first- and second-level subscript and superscript positions.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'smallmatrix' env.
\newcommand\llgg{\mathbin{\begin{smallmatrix} \gg \\ \ll \end{smallmatrix}}}

\begin{document}
$x \llgg y$
\end{document}


I don't think you want to use the symbol also in subscripts or superscripts.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ggll}{\mathrel{\ggll@}}
\newcommand{\ggll@}{%
  \vcenter{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{##\cr$\m@th\gg$\cr\noalign{\kern0.1ex}$\m@th\ll$\cr}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
A \ggll B
\]

\end{document}


A more complete version.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ggll}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\ggll@{\gg\ll}}}
\newcommand{\llgg}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\ggll@{\ll\gg}}}

\newcommand{\ggll@}[2]{\ggll@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\ggll@@}[3]{%
  \vcenter{\offinterlineskip
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\mskip1mu$}%
    \halign{##\cr$\m@th#1#2$\cr\noalign{\kern\wd\z@}$\m@th#1#3$\cr}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
A \ggll B \llgg C_{a\ggll b\llgg c}
\]

\end{document}


